# Calling methods of InputMethodService from Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, inputconnection

Trying to make a custom Keyboard using Jetpack Compose. Cannot figure out how call `currentInputConnection` or other methods from Composable.

```
@Composable
fun CustomKeyboard() {
    
    var inputVal by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(8.dp)
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(50.dp))
        Text("Last key pressed: $inputVal")

        Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), 
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically) 
        {
            MyButton(mText = "A") { inputVal = it}
            MyButton(mText = "B") { inputVal = it}
            MyButton(mText = "C") { inputVal = it}
        }
    }
}

@Composable
private fun MyButton(
    mText: String,
    onPressed: (String) -> Unit
) {
    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = {
            onPressed(mText)
        },
        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
    ) {
        Text(text = mText, fontSize = 30.sp, color = Color.White)
    }
}
```

And the InputMethodService class here...

```
class ComposeKeyboardView(context: Context) : AbstractComposeView(context) {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        CustomKeyboard()
    }
}


class IMEService : InputMethodService(), LifecycleOwner, ViewModelStoreOwner,
    SavedStateRegistryOwner {

    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        val view = ComposeKeyboardView(this)

        window!!.window!!.decorView.let { decorView ->
            ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(decorView, this)
            ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(decorView, this)
            ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(decorView, this)
        }
        view.let {
            ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(it, this)
            ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(it, this)
            ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(it, this)
        }
        return view
    }


    fun doSomethingWith(mData: String) {
        currentInputConnection?.commitText(mData, 1)
    }


    //Lifecylce Methods

    private var lifecycleRegistry: LifecycleRegistry = LifecycleRegistry(this)

    override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
        return lifecycleRegistry
    }


    private fun handleLifecycleEvent(event: Lifecycle.Event) =
        lifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(event)

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        savedStateRegistry.performRestore(null)
        handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    }



    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        handleLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    }


    //ViewModelStore Methods
    private val store = ViewModelStore()

    override fun getViewModelStore(): ViewModelStore = store

    //SaveStateRegestry Methods

    private val savedStateRegistry = SavedStateRegistryController.create(this)

    override fun getSavedStateRegistry(): SavedStateRegistry = savedStateRegistry.savedStateRegistry
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to call a single function, i.e. `doSomethingWith(mData: String)`, or a few of them, then you can pass them into your composables and call them when you want to. This approach would be more loosely coupled and easier to `@Preview` the `CustomKeyboard` composable.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomKeyboard(onKeyPressed: (String) -> Unit) {
    //...
            MyButton(mText = "A") {
                inputVal = it
                onKeyPressed(it)
            }
            // ...
}

class ComposeKeyboardView(
    context: Context,
    private val onKeyPressed: (String) -> Unit,
) : AbstractComposeView(context) {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        CustomKeyboard(onKeyPressed)
    }
}

class IMEService : InputMethodService() {
    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        val view = ComposeKeyboardView(this, onKeyPressed = this::doSomethingWith)
        // ...
        return view
    }

    private fun doSomethingWith(mData: String) {
        currentInputConnection?.commitText(mData, 1)
    }
}
```

If you plan to add many more functions to the `IMEService` that you will have to also call, then you can just pass the `IMEService` (or some interface that `IMEService` implements) into your composables  and then call its members normally. Using an interface over an actual class would make it possible to `@Preview` the `CustomKeyboard` composable.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CustomKeyboard(imeService: IMEService) {
    //...
            MyButton(mText = "A") {
                inputVal = it
                imeService.doSomethingWith(it)
            }
            // ...
}

class ComposeKeyboardView(private val imeService: IMEService) : AbstractComposeView(imeService) {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        CustomKeyboard(imeService)
    }
}

class IMEService : InputMethodService() {
    override fun onCreateInputView(): View {
        val view = ComposeKeyboardView(this)
        // ...
        return view
    }

    fun doSomethingWith(mData: String) {
        currentInputConnection?.commitText(mData, 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer with possible directions. A basic ```interface``` implementation could be third-part of the answer. Obviously useful for future people learning Jetpack Compose.